# When deserializing Jason to ProtoBuffer message null values set to default values

Tags: java, proto

I'm using ProtoBuffer 3 and I have a message that is composed of multiple fields and some of them are other messages that contains some (or all) nullable values.

For example:

```
message MainMessage {
   google.protobuf.StringValue title = 1;
   NotNullable sub1 = 2;
   Nullable sub2 = 3;
   NotNullable sub3 = 4;
}

message NotNullable {
    int64 id = 1;
    string value = 2;
}

message Nullable {
    google.protobuf.Int64Value id = 1;
    google.protobuf.Int64Value value = 2;
}
```

I'm getting the message as a son and I want to deserialize it using the following code:

```
String json = "{\"title\":{\"value\":\"A nice title\"},\"sub1\":{\"id\":{\"value\":1}}}";
MainMessage.Builder message = MainMessage.newBuilder();
JsonFormat.parser().merge(json, message);
```

After running the code above the object that I'm getting contains all of the fields (even that `sub2` and `sub3` are not in the JSON) where the missing data is init to the default value.

for example, the following code will return true:

```
assertTrue(message.getSub2().getId().isInitialized())
assertTrue(message.getSub3().isInitialized())
```

I checked the documentation but couldn't find a way to tell the parse not to set those fields - is there such an option?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue recently. I believe the issue is that your object 'Nullable' isn't itself able to be null - the values within it are, but the object isn't. So when the code is creating the MainMessage, it's initialising sub2 as a non-null, but otherwise completely empty object. I didn't end up finding a solution - in my case I just moved all of the nullable fields up into the one top-level object and it worked okay for my needs - but maybe it'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Kayndarr I've found this article - I'll try to follow it and make my object nullable: https://itnext.io/protobuf-and-null-support-1908a15311b6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this article solves the issue: https://itnext.io/protobuf-and-null-support-1908a15311b6

The way I've implemented it is as follow (sorry for the confusion with the names - I wanted to keep the original names):

```
message MainMessage {
   google.protobuf.StringValue title = 1;
   NotNullable sub1 = 2;
   Nullable sub2 = 3;
   NotNullable sub3 = 4;
}

message NotNullable {
    int64 id = 1;
    string value = 2;
}

message Nullable {
    google.protobuf.Int64Value id = 1;
    google.protobuf.Int64Value value = 2;
}

message AllowNullable {
    oneof kind {
       google.protobuf.NullValue null = 1;
       Nullable value = 2;
}
```

Now all that is required is to use the `has` method before calling the value to check whether or not it's null

For example:

```
if(message.getSub3().hasValue()) {
   // do something...
}
```